# How to get the latest rows in BigQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, how can I get rows based on the latest value of timestamp field?

For example, I have this table.

| first_name | last_name | use_auto | login_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | Davis | true | 2021-05-13 02:00:00 UTC |
| James | Moore | true | 2021-05-13 02:00:01 UTC |
| James | Green | true | 2021-05-13 02:00:02 UTC |
| Edward | Green | false | 2021-05-13 03:00:00 UTC |
| Edward | Wilson | false | 2021-05-13 03:00:01 UTC |
| James | Davis | false | 2021-05-13 03:00:00 UTC |
| James | Moore | false | 2021-05-13 03:00:01 UTC |
| James | Green | false | 2021-05-13 03:00:02 UTC |
| Edward | Green | true | 2021-05-13 02:00:00 UTC |
| Edward | Wilson | true | 2021-05-13 02:00:00 UTC |

I'd like to get the result after query like this,

| first_name | last_name | use_auto | login_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Edward | Green | false | 2021-05-13 03:00:00 UTC |
| Edward | Wilson | false | 2021-05-13 03:00:01 UTC |
| James | Davis | false | 2021-05-13 03:00:00 UTC |
| James | Moore | false | 2021-05-13 03:00:01 UTC |
| James | Green | false | 2021-05-13 03:00:02 UTC |

Please let me know what query should I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convenient way in BigQuery uses aggregation:

```
select array_agg(t order by login_at desc)[ordinal(1)].*
from thistable t
group by first_name, last_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the Gordon's answer: add `limit 1` to reduce memory consumption and increase scalability:

```
select array_agg(t order by login_at desc limit 1)[ordinal(1)].*
from thistable t
group by t.first_name, t.last_name;
```

Comment: I missed something in my question. I edited the table. 
use_auto field can be different.
Could you please let me know the query in this case?

Comment: Updated, following up on the Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why both solution below doesn't work for me, I end up using window function like this:

```
SELECT first_name,  last_name,  use_auto, login_at  
FROM (
  SELECT first_name, last_name, use_auto, login_at
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name ORDER BY login_at DESC) AS rn
  FROM thistable
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

or CTE variant:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT first_name, last_name, use_auto, login_at
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name ORDER BY login_at DESC) AS rn
  FROM thistable
)
SELECT first_name,  last_name,  use_auto, login_at  
FROM t
WHERE rn = 1
```

the logic are:

1. create row number, partition by one that we want to group, in this case: first_name and last_name
2. filter only first row number

this also works if you need 2 latest row of each group, top 3 of group or something similar

**NOTE**: normally in other database (NOT BIGQUERY) that support multiple column matching (PostgreSQL for example), I would do something like this (don't forget to create index on for 3 group columns):

```
SELECT *
FROM thistable
WHERE (first_name, last_name, login_at) IN (
  SELECT first_name, last_name, MAX(login_at)
  FROM thistable
  GROUP BY 1, 2
)
```